# Is the hyper drive a plot hole?

Tags: star-wars, technology, hyperspace

In The Last Jedi, Vice-Admiral Holdo kamakazis' her cruiser by jumping it to hyperspace through the enemy fleet, destroying it in the process.

This seems like an enormous plot hole. Why don't the rebels, or anyone else for that matter, just do this all the time? Just mount a hyperdrive on any object and jump it at the enemy. Judging by the effect that cruiser had on an entire enemy fleet, doing this is has the following properties:

- ignores shields
- super laser damage level
- cannot be dodged
- cheap and easy

Who needs death stars, super star destroyers, or really any planetary destroying tech, when you can just attach a hyperdrive to an asteroid? Furthermore, doesn't this make any ship bigger than an x-wing immediately obsolete? Any large, slow moving targets could be easily be destroyed by a hyperdrive missile. Apparently, you can mount a hyper drive on an A-Wing. Great, take A-Wing hyperdrive out, tape some scrap to it, and all those AT-AT walkers are toast.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: ...Because they aren’t suicide pilots?

Comment: @suchiuomizu Star wars universe has robots that can fly ships, but cant create any with the programming to aim a hyperdrive? Even if you cant, there are lots of people who are motivated enough to sacrifice their lives (i.e. one person) to take out entire fleets. Rebels do suicide missions all. the. time.

Comment: Also, it doesn't need to be kamikaze move. Take a normal missile, replace the normal propulsion system with a hyperdrive and presto - unblockable star destroyer destroyer. The weapon doesn't need someone riding it to work.

Comment: *Are* there missiles in Star Wars?  Mostly they just shoot lasers.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus yeah, they're very common in the games, less so in the movies. But Luke did blow up the first Death star with them.

Comment: @Logister  Why do you assume that larger spaceships would be slower than smaller ones?  On Earth, larger vessels may need to use a highter precentage of their mass and volume for engines in order to travel as fast as smaller vessels, due to increased water or all resistance.  In outer space there is no air and water resistance for vehicles to overcome.  If larger space vehicles with more room use a higher percentage of their mass and volume for engines, they will travel faster than smaller vehicles.

Comment: @M.A.Golding for whatever reason,  the star wars universe tends to have an inverse relationship between size and speed. E.g. fighters are faster and more maneuverable than capital ships. In normal physics maybe you could have dreadnoughts zipping around dodging lasers. In star wars physics star destroyers risk crashing into each other from pure inertia.